# Consider function $y=f(x)$ whose derivative's domain is $\mathbb R$ and $xf'(x)=e^x-1, f(1)=0$. Determine the value of $\int_0^1xf(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Consider function $y = f(x)$ whose derivative's domain is $\mathbb R$ and $xf'(x) = e^x - 1, \forall x \in \mathbb R, f(1) = 0$. Determine the value of $\displaystyle \int_0^1xf(x)\, \mathrm dx$.

[For context, this question is taken from an exam whose format consists of 50 multiple-choice questions with a time limit of 90 minutes. Calculators are the only electronic device allowed in the testing room. (You know those scientific calculators sold at stationery stores and sometimes bookstores? They are the goods.) I need a solution that works within these constraints. Thanks for your cooperation, as always. (Do I need to sound this professional?)

By the way, if the wording of the problem sounds rough, sorry for that. I'm not an expert at translating documents.]

Right, I know what you're thinking. You have that $$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} f'(x) = \dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}, \forall x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} &\implies \int f'(x)\, \mathrm dx = \dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}\, \mathrm dx, \forall x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}\\ &\implies f(x) = \text{Ei}(x) - \ln x + C, \forall x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \end{aligned}$$

And since $f(1) = 0$, it means that $C = -\text{Ei}(1)$.

And subsequently, you have that $\displaystyle f(x) = \text{Ei}(x) - \ln x - \text{Ei}(1), \forall x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, and therefore, $$\begin{aligned} \int_0^1xf(x)\, \mathrm dx &= \int_0^1x[\text{Ei}(x) - \ln x - \text{Ei}(1)]\, \mathrm dx\\ &= \left.\dfrac{1}{2} \times \left[x^2 \times \left(\text{Ei}(x) - \ln x - \text{Ei}(1) + \dfrac{1}{2}\right) - e^x(x - 1)\right]\right|_0^1 = -\dfrac{1}{4} \end{aligned}$$

But that's right, you look in my eyes, straight into my eyes. (See if anyone gets that reference.) And I'll say this, I don't know what the exponential integral is. And for a test that prioritises utilising existing information that 12th-graders already know and not obscure tidbits of mathematical knowledge, this might just not work.

I apologise if I sounded rude, I just really needed to make a point.

So let's try another way. I was thinking of $\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{x^2f'(x)}{2}\, \mathrm dx = \left.\dfrac{x^2f(x)}{2}\right|_0^1 - \int_0^1xf(x)\, \mathrm dx$, but, *(sigh)*, the problem arises again, I can't figure out what $f(x)$ is without the prior knowledge that $\displaystyle \int\dfrac{e^x}{x}\, \mathrm dx = \text{Ei}(x) \setminus \{0\}$.

Here's another idea, what about $$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} xf'(x) = e^x - 1, \forall x \in \mathbb R &\implies \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \dfrac{e^x - 1}{xf(x)}, \forall x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}\\ &\implies \int_0^1\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\, \mathrm dx = \int_0^1\dfrac{e^x - 1}{xf(x)}\, \mathrm dx\\ &\implies \ln|f(1)| - 1 = \int_0^1\dfrac{e^x - 1}{xf(x)}\, \mathrm dx \end{aligned}$$

As always, thanks for reading, (and even more so if you could help), have a great tomorrow, everyone~

Comment: Why do you need “prior knowledge” at $\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2f'(x)}{2}\, \mathrm dx = \left.\dfrac{x^2f(x)}{2}\right|_0^1 - \int_0^1xf(x)\, \mathrm dx$ ? The left-hand side can be computed because $xf'(x)$ is known, and the first term on the right can be computed because $f(1)$ is known.

Comment: Look, looook~ I realised that $\dfrac{0^2f(0)}{2} = 0$ and there's no need to compute $f(0)$ after I've sent my problem off into the Internet, but there've already been answers so I thought I'd just leave that there. I've realised my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^{1} x f(x)&= \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{1}{2} x^2 \right)' f(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} x^2 f(x) \bigg| _0  ^{1} -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} x^2 f'(x) dx \\
&=\left[ \frac{1}{2} 1^2 f(1) -0 \right] -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} x^2 f'(x) dx \\
&=\left[ \frac{1}{2} f(1) -0 \right] -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} x (xf'(x)) dx \\
&=\left[ \frac{1}{2}\cdot 0 -0 \right] -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} x (e^x-1) dx \\
&= 0-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$

The simplest method is to start determining the value of the integral. While calculating it as a "normal" integral you will use the data in the statement.

I think it works the way you started but I think it complicates you too much.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\int_0^1xf(x)=$$
$$\Bigl[\frac{x^2}{2}f(x)\Bigr]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2}f'(x)dx=$$

$$\frac{f(1)}{2}-\frac 12\int_0^1(xe^x-x)dx=$$

$$\frac{-1}{2}\Bigl(\Bigl[xe^x\Bigr]_0^1-\int_0^1e^xdx-\Bigl[\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr]_0^1\Bigr)$$